# How to figure out which UNC path a mapped network drive points to remotely

Tags: network-share, mappeddrive, unc

There is a file server named, `FileServer1`.
On FileServer, there resides a mapped network drive, `F:`.

From my local machine, `Client`, I can get to the F drive using UNC path,
 `\\FileServer1\f$`

Now I'd like to figure out where that `F:` is pointing to from `Client` machine. 
Is there a way to finding that information from Windows Explorer?

Is scripting the only way to find that information from `Client`? (without having to remoting into `FileServer1`.)

If scripting is the only way, how can I find out the information?

Comment: drive f: is a physical drive attached to the server.  admin shares (f$) are only available for local drives so it will always show as f:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F$ is whatever the F: drive is on the server. It's an administrative share. You can get more information by opening the manage menu item from my computer with a right click (or whatever the MMC is in newer windows versions), right click computer management and connect to the server, then go to shared folders, shared. That should tell you active shares.